# set value in cascading autocomplete Dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, dropdown

I simply want that when in "City" ddl ,  "doesnot live in city" option selected ---> in "Chief City"  ddl , "Ville de saint" option  should select automaically .But I am not able to do it ......."Ville de saint" option exist in both dropdowns ....My situation is stuck like this ..

[image]

This is the Code for Dropdowns :

```
  <div>          
   @Html.DropDownList(Model.townProp, new SelectList(Bmsa.UI.Utility.Utility.GetTown(Model.townId), "Value", "Text", Model.townId), new { onchange = "GetchiefTown();" }) </div>

   <div> @Html.DropDownList(Model.chiefTownProp, new SelectList(Bmsa.UI.Utility.Utility.GetchiefTown(Model.communeId), "Value", "Text", Model.chiefTownId))</div>
```

I have Tried some following functions based on some post, but not able to get the results :

```
    function GetchiefTown() {

    $('#@Model.chiefTownProp').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
    $('#@Model.chiefTownProp').attr('selectedIndex', 2);
    $('#@Model.chiefTownProp').val("Ville de saint louis de Nord");
    $('#@Model.chiefTownProp').val(2);
    $('#@Model.chiefTownProp').prop('selected', true);
    }
```

for autocomplete feature I have used jquery Select() plugin . the DOM for dropdowns in browser look like this

[image]

Do I need to anything different due to this Plugin ?

Can anybody suggest What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a change handler to city option. When doesnot live in city is selected the change handler set Chief City to Ville de saint. For give a simple example, we have two selects like this:

```
<label>City:</label>
  <select id="city">
    <option value="1">Select Below</option>
    <option value="2">Doesnot live in city</option>
    <option value="3">Live in city</option>  
  </select>

  <label>Chief city:</label>
  <select id="chief-city">
    <option value="1">Select Below</option>
    <option value="2">Ville de saint</option>
    <option value="3">Other city</option>
  </select>
```

And the simple jQuery code:

```
$('#city').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 2)
    $('#chief-city').val('2');
  else
    $('#chief-city').val('1');
});
```

If the **#city** **select** is changed the change handler will verify the value in **#city** **select**, in this example if the value is 2 this menas that "**doesnot live in city**" is selected then the selected option in **#chief-city select** will be **Ville de saint**

This is a fiddle with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/alissonmbr/dqzkkzdm/